# In Oracle SQL , what is the maximum number of AND clauses in a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, boundary

More of a curious question .. Studying a SQL and I want to know about what is the maximum number of AND clauses:

```
WHERE condition1
AND condition2
AND condition3
AND condition4
...
AND condition?
...
AND condition_n;
```

i.e what isthe biggest possible `n` ? It would seem that since these could be trivial comparisons, the limit it high.
How far can one go before reach limit?

[src](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Practically, there is no limit.

Most tools will have some limit on the length of the SQL statement that they can deal with.  If you want to get really deep into the weeds, though, you could use the `dbms_sql` package which accepts a collection of `varchar2(4000)` that comprise a single SQL statement.  That would get you up to 2^32 * 4000 bytes.  If we assume that every condition is at least 10 bytes, that puts a reasonable upper limit of 400 * 2^32 which is roughly 800 billion conditions.  If you're getting anywhere close to that, you're doing something really wrong.  Most tools will have limits that kick in well before that.

Of course, if you did create the largest possible SQL statement using `dbms_sql`, that SQL statement would require ~16 trillion bytes.  A single SQL statement that required 16 TB of storage would probably create other issues...

Comment: That actually then proves that ... there is no limit. it will then be bound by the memory capacity etc. cause no any practical scenario will need 800M condition ... at least to my knowledge. Nice deduction though.

Answer (score 3):

I put together a simple test case:

```
select * from dual
where 1=1
and 1=1
...
```

Using SQL*Plus, I was able to run with 100,000 conditions (admittedly, very simple ones) without an issue. I'd find any use case that came even close to approaching that number to be highly suspect...

Comment: check the explain plan, Oracle might be smart enough to just select * from dual;

Comment: @tbone: It certainly did optimize away the conditions, but it still had to parse the whole thing before it could do that.

Comment: true, parsing would be first, but if there was a limit (which I doubt), would the limit be in the parsing or in the optimization stage?  Anyway, this entire question seems a bit silly, but something we both wanted to spend time on anyway ;)  +1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about that cause I don't think even in Oracle spec they have defined it but on few factor this would be determined.

1. length of the query. In few Oracle community/forum post I have read that in `oracle 9i` the maximum length of an SQL statement is 64k but in later version that limit is not specified rather it's specified saying `depends on disk space, memory availability etc`.
2. Again, in few Oracle forum I have read that, Oracle support 1000 element in INLIST (`IN (a1,a2,...,a1000)`). So it will get converted to 1000 `OR` condition like `a1 OR a2 Or ... OR a1000`. With that, my understanding is, if it supports 1000 `OR` condition; it will be able to cope up with same number of `AND` condition as well.

But ultimately, I don't think there is any documented limit/upperbound present.

Comment: Tom Kyte claims the 64K limit was a documentation bug (and has proven that it was not enforced). https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:41742083561301

Comment: @Allan, Ahh!!! if spec itself is wrong then I am helpless :) but still the points holds though .. if there is any limit to the query string then all your condition will have to abide by that.